# Trying to set up hotkeys for Playstation 2 emulator using programming

Tags: scripting, macros, game-development

I use PCSx2 on my pc to emulate a PS2. I am trying to set up a keyboard/mouse control scheme (I use lilypad), which for the most part is pretty simple. Here is the dilenma I have been trying to solve for years and have never found on answer on the Pcsx2 forums: I need to set up the control layout so that the w,a,s,d keys are assigned to the left stick with half-sensitivity, and then have Shift+w,a,s,d assigned to the left stick with full sensitivity. It sounds straight-forward, but lilypad has no mechanism to assign a command to multiple keys such as Shift+(key). This would allow games like SOCOM to be controlled just like as if it was a PC game, where shift enables running otherwise you are just walking, and it would be awesome! I have tried different macro programs (such as G-hotkey, macrogamer) but neither can accomplish this. My intention would be to assign the keys from within lilypad to 2 different sets of keys(i.e. arrow keys for left stick with half-sensitivity, and i,j,k,l for left stick with full sensitivity) , and then use an external program to assign those keys to w,a,s,d and shift+w,a,s,d while in-game. So far I have not been able to get it working, so I thought I'd try a different approach. Does anyone have a solution that I could try, maybe a program I could write or a script?